# Particular Integral of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Question:** The partial differential equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=x,$$ has

1. only one particular integral.
2. a particular integral which is linear in $x$ and $y$.
3. a particular integral which is a quadratic polynomial is $x$ and $y$.
4. more than one particular integral.

**Answer:** Is the option (4) correct and all others are false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If we set

$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}x^3+Ax+By+C$$

then it will be a solution for any real values of $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: @HR, thanks for your efforts. What can we conclude about the option (2) and (4)?

Comment: @Warrior: As this is not linear in $x$ then option 2 is false. :) So "obtaining more than one particular integral" is the best choice which is option 4. :)

Comment: @H.R. When I calculated the PI then i got $\frac{x^3}{6}$, how did you get something involving $y$ also?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: Sorry for the delay. I was not around here for a while. How did you take the PI? I just gave an answer out of my pocket! :) Of course, I noted that the right side of PDE does not depend on $y$. So  any function satisfying $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$ can be added to a particular answer like $\frac 16 x^3$! :)

Comment: Ok so we can do that always right? Got it. THanks for responding.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: Whenever you have **linear** PDEs, you can do this. :)